# Django_Rest_Framework Serializer Field "source" attribute is not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a DRF Serializer that uses different names for the fields than the underlying Django Model.  I thought that this is what the  "source" attribute was for.

Here is some code:

**models.py:**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):     
    my_snake_case_field = models.DateTimeField()
```

**serializers.py**:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'myCamelCaseField', )

        myCamelCaseField = serializers.DateTimeField(source='my_snake_case_field')
```

But when I try to view that I get the following error:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /api/mymodel/1/ Field name `myCamelCaseField`
>   is not valid for model `MyModel`.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I guess you're referencing after calling the parameter. the code is unreachable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a **`Indentation`** error, It should not inside the `Meta` class

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    myCamelCaseField = serializers.DateTimeField(source='my_snake_case_field')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'myCamelCaseField',)
```

Comment: Argh!  That was it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for instance:

Now you've assigned `myCamelCaseField` before calling it.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    myCamelCaseField = serializers.DateTimeField(source='my_snake_case_field')
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'myCamelCaseField', )
```